# In Excel to run solver in a loop to optimize a objective cell with constraints

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, solver

I'm completely new to VBA, MACRO. I need to a loop to optimize a

- First it has to run the objective function cell(N10) with a constraints cell (R10)
- Then it should shift to the next column for both objective and constraint .i.e for Cell O10 & Cell S10, similarly for 2 more times.
- Then it should shift to i+9 th row and repeat the same step analysis.

There are two loops to be precise, one for column loop 4 times and row loop, till it reaches end.

[Excel snapshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAoq6.png)

Comment: A screenshot of your code is a poor way of providing examples of what you have done.

Comment: Pardon! I'm a begineer. Will learn how to represent it in a reproducible way. And thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues ...

- You should always use Option Explicit in your code. This will help capture errors due to type mismatches.
- When using `Cells(x,y)`, you should always qualify it with the worksheet.
- Although using Ranges as input to Solver routines appears to work sometimes, it is a better practice to always use strings.
- SolverReset will cause Excel to flip to manual calculation mode. When used in a loop like this, you should call it first, not last.
- In SolverOK, specifying both the Engine and EngineDesc can cause a mismatch leading to failure. I recommend always omitting EngineDesc.
- It is unclear what your "ByChange" field in SolverOK should be. I assume it the same as your constraint, but you will need to resolve this.
- Without sample data from you, this has not been tested.

The following code should achieve your objectives, with appropriate modifications as flagged.

```
Option Explicit
Sub mySolve()
Dim totalrows As Long
totalrows = 1000 ' *** use whatever formula finds your last row

Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim myWS As Worksheet
Dim SetAddr As String, ChgAddr As String, ConAddr As String

Set myWS = ActiveSheet
For row = 10 To totalrows Step 9
    For col = 14 To 17 Step 1
        SetAddr = myWS.Cells(row, col).Address
        ChgAddr = myWS.Cells(row, col + 4).Address '*** you don't specify in your question
        ConAddr = myWS.Cells(row, col + 4).Address
        SolverReset
        SolverOk SetCell:=SetAddr, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=ChgAddr, Engine:=3
        SolverAdd CellRef:=ConAddr, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="2" '*** what is your constraint
        SolverSolve Userfinish:=True
    Next col
Next row

End Sub
```